# handle empty response from http get call

Tags: python, rest

I have  a  http get call  in a  self.method() which  returns  only   [ ]   in the   response  link  in some cases. I want to use   this  output   to handle exception in another  method, like

```
if type(self.method()) is 'NoneType':
   print "The object   is  not  present"
else:
    self.method2()
```

I am   getting  errors 
like

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'URL'
```

How to catch the  response output [] in if statement ?

Comment: Are you coming from JavaScript? The Pythonic way to do this check is `if self.method() is None`. Or just `if self.method()` if the method can't return falsy values like `0`, `False` or `[]`.

Comment: Thanks much that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `self.method()` returns `[]` if the `get` failed:

```
response = self.method()
if not response:
    print 'response missing'
else:
    do_things(reponse)
```

this snippet uses the fact that an implicit `bool()` is cast on `response` which evaluates to `False` if the list is empty. it's basically a more readable version of: `if response == []`